# How to combine lists by choosing one element per index?

Tags: python, list, iteration, generator

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function that takes two lists, then returns a list of all the possible combinations of those lists made by choosing one element from one of the lists per index.  I don't think I'm describing it well, but what I'm looking for is:

input:
['a','b'], ['c','d']

output:
['ab', 'ad', 'cb', 'cd']

I've made a function that does this semi-successfully here:

```
def mix_list(lst1, lst2):
    res = []
    k = max(len(lst1), len(lst2))
    ref = itertools.product(range(2), repeat=k)

    for comb in list(ref):
        temp = [None] * k
        for i, e in enumerate(comb):
            if e == 0:
                try:
                    temp[i] = lst1[i]
                except IndexError:
                    temp[i] = lst2[i]
            elif e == 1:
                try:
                    temp[i] = lst2[i]
                except IndexError:
                    temp[i] = lst1[i]
        res.append(temp)
    return [''.join(i) for i in set(map(tuple, res))]
```

My first thought was that itertools would have some function that would accomplish this, but I couldn't find anything.  Besides that, I did some googling and searching on here, but I haven't been able to find something that does what I'm looking for a bit faster or a bit more simply.

Is there a better way to accomplish this, or maybe a library that has a function that already does this?

Comment: why `'ab'`? It use two indexes from first list and zero indexes from second list.

Comment: It's choosing one element from either list per index, not per list.  So for each output, output[0] can be input_1[0] or input2[0], and output[1] can be input_1[1] or input_2[1].Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, now it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip()` the two lists together to get a list of pairs of the values at corresponding indices, and then use `product()` to get all the combinations of picking one element at each index:

```
>>> lst1, lst2 = ['a','b'], ['c','d']
>>> list(product(*zip(lst1, lst2)))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

This can easily be extended to an arbitrary number and length of lists, but the size of the result will grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert

```
['a','b'], ['c','d']
```

to

```
['a','c'], ['b','d']
```

(first list has values for index 1, second list has values for index 2)

and then use `itertools.product()`

```
import itertools 

a, b = zip(['a','b'], ['c','d'])
#print(a, b)  # ['a','c'], ['b','d']

data = itertools.product(a, b)

data = ["".join(item) for item in data]

print(data)
```

Result

```
['ab', 'ad', 'cb', 'cd']
```